# Attendance self-tracking

Tags: android, time-management

I heard that there are Android applications to track my daily attendance, which use the office wifi connection times to determine arrival/exit.

Can anyone please point me to application names?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. What features do you need? What is your price limit? From your description, any [work-time tracker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_timetracking) based on WiFi for auto-punching on/off would do as well?

Comment: Why not ask whomever you hear this from?